# Swipe влево в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть адаптер, который позволяет вывести в `RecyclerView` список категорий. Нужно сделать возможность свайпа влево для элементов списка. Когда пользователь делает свайп влево должны отображаться две кнопки "Редактировать" и "Удалить". При нажатии на редактировать открывается активити для редактирования куда передается id категории, а при нажатии на удалить элемент удаляется из списка, а также из БД.

В интернете есть немало примеров для реализации свайпа, но непонятно как их применить. Если есть источник, где доступно и понятно объясняется как реализовать такое подскажите пожалуйста или тут дайте ответ. Спасибо.

Адаптер

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.CategoryViewHolder> {

    private List<Category> categoryList;
    private Context mContext;

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int categoryID, String categoryName);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, List<Category> categoryList){
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public RoundedImageView imgCategory;
        public TextView txtCategory;


        public CategoryViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCategory);
            imgCategory = (RoundedImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgCategory);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(categoryList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId(), categoryList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_category,parent,false);
        CategoryViewHolder vh = new CategoryViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final Category category = categoryList.get(position);
        holder.txtCategory.setText(category.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return categoryList.size();
    }

}
```

Activity

```
public class CategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CategoryAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    private RecyclerView rvCategory;
    private CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_category);

        rvCategory = findViewById(R.id.rvCategory);

        rvCategory.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        MYDabaBase db = AppDatabase.getInstance().getMYDabaBase();
        CategoryDao categoryDao = db.categoryDao();

        categoryDao.getCategories().observe(this, (List<Category> categoryList) -> {
            categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(CategoryActivity.this, categoryList);
            categoryAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            rvCategory.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int categoryID, String categoryName) {
        //
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы вам предложил немного изменить принцип работы, а именно сделать свайп влево - удаление (по аналогу с тем же Gmail), а свайп вправо - редактирование. Я сделал у себя в проекте удаление таким образом.

1. Сделать класс отвечающий за само движение:

   ```
   abstract public class SwipeToDeleteCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.Callback {

   Context mContext;
   private Paint mClearPaint;
   private ColorDrawable mBackground;
   private int backgroundColor;
   private Drawable deleteDrawable;
   private int intrinsicWidth;
   private int intrinsicHeight;


   SwipeToDeleteCallback(Context context) {
       mContext = context;
       mBackground = new ColorDrawable();
       backgroundColor = Color.parseColor("#b80f0a");
       mClearPaint = new Paint();
       mClearPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
       deleteDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_delete);
       intrinsicWidth = Objects.requireNonNull(deleteDrawable).getIntrinsicWidth();
       intrinsicHeight = deleteDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();


   }


   @Override
   public int getMovementFlags(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
       return makeMovementFlags(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
       return false;
   }

   @Override
   public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
       super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

       View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
       int itemHeight = itemView.getHeight();

       boolean isCancelled = dX == 0 && !isCurrentlyActive;

       if (isCancelled) {
           clearCanvas(c, itemView.getRight() + dX, (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
           super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
           return;
       }

       mBackground.setColor(backgroundColor);
       mBackground.setBounds(itemView.getRight() + (int) dX, itemView.getTop(), itemView.getRight(), itemView.getBottom());
       mBackground.draw(c);

       int deleteIconTop = itemView.getTop() + (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2;
       int deleteIconMargin = (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2;
       int deleteIconLeft = itemView.getRight() - deleteIconMargin - intrinsicWidth;
       int deleteIconRight = itemView.getRight() - deleteIconMargin;
       int deleteIconBottom = deleteIconTop + intrinsicHeight;


       deleteDrawable.setBounds(deleteIconLeft, deleteIconTop, deleteIconRight, deleteIconBottom);
       deleteDrawable.draw(c);

       super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);


   }

   private void clearCanvas(Canvas c, Float left, Float top, Float right, Float bottom) {
       c.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, mClearPaint);

   }

   @Override
   public float getSwipeThreshold(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
       return 0.7f;
   }
   ```

   }
2. И подключить его в активности:

   ```
   private void enableSwipeToDeleteAndUndo() {
       SwipeToDeleteCallback swipeToDeleteCallback = new SwipeToDeleteCallback(getActivity()) {
           @Override
           public void onSwiped(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
               тут можно выполнить действие
       };

       ItemTouchHelper itemTouchhelper = new ItemTouchHelper(swipeToDeleteCallback);
       itemTouchhelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
   }
   ```

вам же нужно будет добавить иконку для редактирования, и обработку свайпа. Саму реализацию взял [отсюда](https://www.journaldev.com/23164/android-recyclerview-swipe-to-delete-undo) надеюсь и вам поможет. Удачи :)

Comment: Спасибо. Решил сделать по такому же принципу. свайпы с разных сторон отвечают за разные действия.